# Laravel json format responce from mysql data

Tags: массивы, json, laravel, php7, mariadb

**Laravel 5.8.5

MariaDB 10.3.11

php 7.2.11**

Необходимо вытащить список клиентов и их количество:

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT count(*) AS `cnt`, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS `dealsIds` FROM clients GROUP BY id;');
$header = array ('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'charset' => 'utf-8');
return response()->json($data,200,$header,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Проблема в том, что список клиентов он воспринимает как строку, а нам **нужен массив**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поиграться с конкатом, и доставить скобки, можно "нарисовать" массив, но это все-равно будет строка в кавычках. Как дать понять ларавелу и/или Mysql что мы хотим видеть там массив?
Эксперименты с https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html положительного результата не дали.
Есть вариант вытащить этот список отдельным запросом без group_concat и руками объединить в один массив, тогда все будет работать. Но хотелось бы сделать все в рамках одного запроса без лишней логики на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно при использовании GROUP_CONCAT будет строка. + У этой функции есть ограничения по количеству символов.
Лучше используй вариант такой (будет намного быстрей):

```
$data = DB::table('clients')->get(['id']);
return response()->json([
   'count' => $data->count(),
   'deals_ids' => $data->toArray()
],200);
```